# How to set two default values for a Silex or Symfony2 route?

Tags: symfony, routes, silex

I have defined a route like below in Silex. I assume it can be done in symfony2 with annotations (conceptually).

```
$app->get('/get/all/entities/page/{page}/limit/{limit}', function ($page, $limit) use ($app) {

    // Build response 
    return new Response($response);

})->value('page', 1)->value('limit', 20);
```

With default values like above, how the route can be used without specifying the `page` and `limit`?

For example, if I define something like below, I can just browse to `http://www.exmpale.com/get/all/entities/page` and everything would be fine and the default value for `page` will be `1`:

```
$app->get('/get/all/entities/page/{page}', function ($page) use ($app) {

        // Build response 
        return new Response($response);

    })->value('page', 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following:

```
$app->get('/page/{page}/{limit}', function($page, $limit) use ($app) {
    return 'Page: ' . $page . ', limit: ' . $limit;
})->value('page', 1)->value('limit', 30);
```

Here are the outputs I get for different urls:

- `http://localhost:8888/playground/silex/web/page        ---> Page: 1, limit: 30`
- `http://localhost:8888/playground/silex/web/page/3      ---> Page: 3, limit: 30`
- `http://localhost:8888/playground/silex/web/page/54/100 ---> Page: 54, limit: 100`

So, everything is working as expected, the values are correctly set. The problem with your url is the static part between the parameters ...{page}/**limit**/{limit}. If you have a static part between your parameters everything works, except that you cannot call the url with a default first parameter, at least I am not aware of any possible ways to do that

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony2 this can be done very easily. Default values for placeholders are set in a routing file:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#required-and-optional-placeholders

**UPDATE:**

In your case, your entry in routing file would look like this (YAML):

```
your_route:
    path:      /get/all/entities/page/limit
    defaults:  { _controller: YourBundle:YourController:YourAction, page: 1, limit: 2 }
```

Comment: I am talking about more than one default! `/page/{page}/limit/{limit}`, 2 defaults: `page` and `limit`.

Comment: just list them all separated by comma

Comment: Are you serious? It is not a hack. This is documented feature. http://pastebin.com/kNKWNRpz

Comment: in your update, how do you pass new values? let's say you need page 2 limit 100!

Comment: try `/get/all/entities/page/{page}/limit/{limit}` as a path

Comment: Read the documentation I post a link to.

Answer (score 0):

From symfony documentation:

> Of course, you can have more than one optional placeholder (e.g.
>   /blog/{slug}/{page}), but everything after an optional placeholder
>   must be optional. For example, /{page}/blog is a valid path, but page
>   will always be required (i.e. simply /blog will not match this route).

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#required-and-optional-placeholders